# Amazon kinesis multiple publishers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have checked while pushing records if we have 2 shards say shard1 & shard2 and two different producer lambdas we can use partition key attribute to put to different shards.

I have a few questions:

1. If multiple publishers say two lambda are pushing to a kinesis stream with a single shard, will it cause any race condition? Is it possible two different sources can push to single shard?
2. Which one is recommended different shards for each producer or single for multiple producers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons to use multiple shards in a Kinesis stream.

The primary is throughput. There are limits on how much data you can write to (or read from) a shard, as well as how many write operations you can perform per minute. If your stream has a higher incoming rate, you have no choice but to use more shards.

Another use-case is what you pointed out, partitioning events based on some parameter, maybe because you want to use different consumers, or maybe because you deem some events have higher priority than others.

Having multiple producers is not a reason to have multiple shards. Race conditions do not happen. Just be aware of your total incoming throughput.